# Getting zonal statistics of polygons not touching center raster cells in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, zonal-statistics

I'm working a postgis processing zonal stats from raster and I couldn't manage the problem of raster with so low resolution (like 9km width) and small polygons.

My problem is, these rasters are big (for all South America) if I try to resample the pixels to smaller ones, it will spend a lot of time.

There are a possible solution using the `ST_SummaryStats()` style, like my example code bellow.

I try this code and it only get stats when the polygon covers the centroid of pixel image.

```sql
SELECT
  gid,
  St_SummaryStats(St_Union(ST_Clip(ST_SetSRID(rast, 4326), 1, ST_SetSRID(geom, 4326), 0.0, true)))
FROM raster_image, shape_polygons
WHERE st_intersects(ST_SetSRID(rast, 4326), ST_SetSRID(the_geom, 4326))
GROUP BY gid;
```

#### The Example:

[image: example of big pixels and small polygons]

#### The results of Stats

[image: stats results]

Comment: Which stats are you interested in? You can use ST_NearestValue if you just want the raster value, and this should work even if the centroid is not covered by your polygon/

Comment: I need to get at least  mean, standard deviation and count.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When pixels are large comparing with polygons you better go "vector way". i.e. vectorize the raster tiles and then procede to a vector/vector intersection/computation. If you use the PostGIS Addons, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT gt.id,
       (aws).geom,
       (aws).totalarea,
       (aws).weightedmean,
FROM (SELECT id, ST_AreaWeightedSummaryStats(gv) aws
      FROM (SELECT ST_Intersection(rt.rast, gt.geom) gv
            FROM rasttable rt, geomtable gt
            WHERE ST_Intersects(rt.rast, gt.geom)
           ) foo1
      GROUP BY gt.id
     ) foo2;
```

Comment: Source for [Postgis addons](https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons). I am glad that Pierre has answered this because he is the expert in Postgis raster. I was going to suggest vector to vector as the way forward, but was concerned there might be a better way. Apparently not.

Comment: @pierre-racine how to install your Postgis package functions?
Only to left in Postgis folder? I found your blog with some instructions, but I couldn't figure how to work correctly  [Pierre Racine - Geospatial Elucubrations](http://geospatialelucubrations.blogspot.com/2013/11/launching-postgis-add-ons-new-postgis.html)
Ps.: I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: Just execute the postgis_addons.sql file in PgAdmin (or with PSQL). You can then run the test file postgis_addons_test.sql